# Using an IIF statement in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, where-clause

I am trying to add multiple criteria to a Where clause in SQL Server 2014 using the following code and I am getting a syntax error.

I have tried a case statement but cannot get that to work based on the examples on this site.

```
Where  
iif(ss.DATAAREAID = 'USMF',
 (ss.ITEMGROUPID like 'S%' and  ss.ITEMGROUPID  not like 'SMS%'),
(ss.ITEMGROUPID like 'SW%' and  ss.ITEMGROUPID  like 'SS%')
```

I am sure it is a quick solution, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql

Comment: Never mind me, need to update my SQL Server knowledge apparently.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use conditional logic.  Just use boolean expressions:

```
Where (ss.DATAAREAID = 'USMF', and ss.ITEMGROUPID like 'S%' and ss.ITEMGROUPID  not like 'SMS%') or
      (ss.DATAAREAID <> 'USMF' and ss.ITEMGROUPID like 'SW%' and ss.ITEMGROUPID  like 'SS%')
```

Note:  `iif()` is a SQL Server function, but it was introduced for backwards compatibility to MS Access.  You should use ANSI-standard `case` expressions instead.

Your version doesn't work because SQL Server does not treat the result of a boolean expression as a valid value.  You would need to do something like this:

```
where (case when . . . and . . . then 1
            else 0
       end) = 1
```

The above does not take `NULL` values into account.  That condition is easily added if needed.